# Linux - 32bit compiled sem_timedwait example (with small mod) fails on 64 bit when libasan is used

Tags: c, linux, semaphore, 32bit-64bit, address-sanitizer

I was having a problem with one application, so i went back to the basics and grabbed the sem_timedwait example from the ubuntu focal online manpages. I modified it slightly to repro the problem.

CASE: sem_post before sem_timedwait
EXPECTED: sem_timedwait to succeed immediately
OBTAINED: sem_timedwait times out

The problem was showing initially on a Docker (WSL disabled) container with Ubuntu 20.04 (g++ 9 multilib)
I then tried from a WSL Debian 9 (g++ 6 multilib) and a WSL Ubuntu 20.04 (g++ 9 multilib) installed fresh from PowerShell
I further installed a full fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VM with g++ 9 multilib on Hyper-V

I also tried apt update && apt upgrade to be sure to be on the latest packages, I also tried at some point to completely remove g++ 9 and all its dependencies and use g++ 10 (which comes with libasan.so.6 instead of libasan.so.5)

[Original sem_timedwait example from Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man3/sem_wait.3.html)

Modified version, added a sleep before sem_timedwait so that the call to sem_timedwait happens always after the sem_post. I also added a print of sem_getvalue to verify that the semaphore counter was being incremented correctly to 1.

[File: test_sem.cpp]

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

sem_t sem;

#define handle_error(msg) \
   do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void
handler(int sig)
{
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, "sem_post() from handler\n", 24);
   if (sem_post(&sem) == -1) {
       write(STDERR_FILENO, "sem_post() failed\n", 18);
       _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct sigaction sa;
   struct timespec ts;
   int s;

   if (argc != 3) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <alarm-secs> <wait-secs>\n",
               argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (sem_init(&sem, 0, 0) == -1)
       handle_error("sem_init");

   /* Establish SIGALRM handler; set alarm timer using argv[1] */

   sa.sa_handler = handler;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   sa.sa_flags = 0;
   if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL) == -1)
       handle_error("sigaction");

   alarm(atoi(argv[1]));

   /* Calculate relative interval as current time plus
      number of seconds given argv[2] */

   if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
       handle_error("clock_gettime");

   ts.tv_sec += atoi(argv[2]);
   //this is a cancellation point when the alarm goes off
   sleep(atoi(argv[1]) + 2);
   
   int value = 0;
   
   sem_getvalue(&sem, &value);
   
   printf("sem_getvalue(): %d\n", value);

   sleep(2);

   printf("main() about to call sem_timedwait()\n");
   while ((s = sem_timedwait(&sem, &ts)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
       continue;       /* Restart if interrupted by handler */

   /* Check what happened */

   if (s == -1) {
       if (errno == ETIMEDOUT)
           printf("sem_timedwait() timed out\n");
       else
           perror("sem_timedwait");
   } else
       printf("sem_timedwait() succeeded\n");

   exit((s == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

to compile this example i used the following

`g++ -std=gnu++17 -m32 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope -fno-omit-frame-pointer test_sem.cpp -lstdc++ -lpthread -lasan`

to run it, simply `./a.out 2 5`

what I obtain is the following unexpected result:

```
sem_post() from handler
sem_getvalue(): 1
main() about to call sem_timedwait()
sem_timedwait() timed out
```

the same code compiled WITHOUT the `-m32` flag `g++ -std=gnu++17 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope -fno-omit-frame-pointer  test_sem.cpp -lstdc++ -lpthread -lasan` gives me the following expected result

```
sem_post() from handler
sem_getvalue(): 1
main() about to call sem_timedwait()
sem_timedwait() succeeded
```

the same code compiled WITH the `-m32` flag but WITHOUT the libasan `g++ -std=gnu++17 -m32 test_sem.cpp -lstdc++ -lpthread -lasan` gives me the following expected result:

```
sem_post() from handler
sem_getvalue(): 1
main() about to call sem_timedwait()
sem_timedwait() succeeded
```

Just for the sake of me I tried also to replace the signal handler code with a second thread to achieve the same sem_post before sem_timedwait and I obtain the same exact result. I further tried also using the non-POSIX-compliant sem_clockwait using both CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC and I got the same exact result.

I also tried completely removing g++ 9 and installed g++ 10 (which uses libasan.so.6 instead of libasan.so.5)

Right now I dont know if it is something on my side but seems that Docker Ubuntu 20.04 (no WSL), Debian 9 WSL 2, Ubuntu 20.04 WLS 2, and full Hyper-V Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 20.04 are all giving me the same result.

I tried everything I could think of to no avail.

Comment: I don't have an answer, however, I have observed this exact behavior. I stepped through the underlying library calls made by sem_init() and sem_timedwait(). When asan was enabled I saw that sem_init() was using __old_sem_init() and sem_timedwait() was using __new_sem_wait_fast(). These implementations in glibc are not compatible (See: https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/nptl/sem_init.c.html) hence the semaphores were not working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the finding. This is interesting. I have no time currently to work on this, but I hope I can look into it in the future